# php simple rand() look up taking long / crashing browser?

Tags: php, random, browser, fatal-error

I'm running this code:

```
$n1 = rand(1,20);
$n2 = rand(1,20);
echo '<p>Looking for ' . $z1;
echo '<p>looking....<br><br>';
for ($i = 1; $n1 != $n2; $i ++) {
  $n2 = rand(1,10);
}

echo '<p>I tried ' . $i . ' times.</p>';
```

First loads of the page are usually super fast. Then suddenly:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded

It's either working super fast or crashing. Can someone help me understand why this is?

Thank You

Comment: Your loop terminates when `$n1` ==`$n2`, but you never change either of them. Your script will either terminate immediately or run forever

Comment: I change it in the for statement...

Comment: It must be a caching thing I guess...

Comment: No - look again at the code you posted. You set the values of `$n1` and `$n2` in the first two lines. You're not changing them in the `for` statement, or anywhere else.

Comment: Ah. You're right. But the code is working here. Just changed it to english to post here. Sorry for that. It's $n2 oc.

Comment: In your code as you now have it, if `$n1` == `$n2` your loop will terminate immediately. If `$n1` is initialised to some value <= 10 your loop will probably terminate eventually, but it could run for a long time, and there's a non-zero chance that it won't terminate at all. If `$n1` is initialised to some value > 10 your loop will never terminate.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what output you expect from this. Fiddling with the variable will deliver some result, but it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Thank You man. Made me realize I need sleep. Should be rand(1,20). I'm learning all this numbers stuff and want to run some simulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have committed a "logic" mistake.

If `$n1 = rand(1,20);` sets `$n1` to any  number from `11` to `20`, then the condition in your loop will never be satisfied and result in an "infinite loop".

In other words, roughly half of your code executions will result in infinite loops and half will not.

`$n2 = rand(1,10);` needs to be `$n2 = rand(1,20);` so that all possible `$n1` values can be matched.

Might I recommend:

```
$n = rand(1, 20);
echo "<p>Looking for $n</p>";
$i = 0;
do {
    ++$i;
} while($n != rand(1, 20));

echo "<p>Tries: $i </p>";
```

Ultimately, whenever a random generator is used to determine a loop's break condition, it can be sensible to set an arbitrary "maximum iterations" value.  Once that is reached, let your script exit the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if there's an accepted answer here, but my suggestion would be to add the following lines.  I suggest using a while instead of a for:

```
$n1 = rand(1,20);
$n2 = rand(1,20);
echo '<p>Looking for ' . $z1;
echo '<p>looking....<br><br>';
$cnt=0;
while ($n1 != $n2) {
   $n2 = rand(1,10);
   $cnt++;
}
echo '<p>I tried ' . $cnt . ' times.</p>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.  To be as helpful as possible to others, please share why my post was downvoted.  Perhaps I can adjust it to be more helpful.